# OpenCV : tuple has no attribute copy

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box

I am trying to generate bounding boxes near the image, but getting tuple has no attribute error. The contours from the images are passed to "blobbify", which returns the contours of the blob.

Here is the code

```
# erodes image based on given kernel size (erosion = expands black areas)
def erode( img, kern_size = 3 ):
    retval, img = cv2.threshold(img, 254.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) # threshold to deal with only black and white.
    kern = np.ones((kern_size,kern_size),np.uint8) # make a kernel for erosion based on given kernel size.
    eroded = cv2.erode(img, kern, 1) # erode your image to blobbify black areas
    y,x = eroded.shape # get shape of image to make a white boarder around image of 1px, to avoid problems with find contours.
    return cv2.rectangle(eroded, (0,0), (x,y), (255,255,255), 1)

# finds contours of eroded image
def prep( img, kern_size = 3 ):    
    img = erode( img, kern_size )
    retval, img = cv2.threshold(img, 200.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) #   invert colors for findContours
    return cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # Find Contours of Image

# given img & number of desired blobs, returns contours of blobs.
def blobbify(img, num_of_labels, kern_size = 3, dilation_rate = 10):
    print(type(img))
    prep_img, contours, hierarchy = prep( img.copy(), kern_size ) # dilate img and check current contour count.
    while len(contours) > num_of_labels:
        kern_size += dilation_rate # add dilation_rate to kern_size to increase the blob. Remember kern_size must always be odd.
        previous = (prep_img, contours, hierarchy)
        processed_img, contours, hierarchy = prep( img.copy(), kern_size ) # dilate img and check current contour count, again.
    if len(contours) < num_of_labels:
        return (processed_img, contours, hierarchy)
    else:
        return previous

# finds bounding boxes of all contours
def bounding_box(contours):
    bBox = []
    for curve in contours:
        box = cv2.boundingRect(curve)
    bBox.append(box)
    return bBox
```

I got this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-155-5f2b07e02ca2> in <module>()
     43 e_i = erode(img,kern_size=3)
     44 c_i = prep(e_i)
---> 45 b_i = blobbify(c_i,num_of_labels=5,kern_size=3,dilation_rate=10)
     46 bbox_img = bounding_box(b_i)
     47 

<ipython-input-155-5f2b07e02ca2> in blobbify(img, num_of_labels, kern_size, dilation_rate)
     19 def blobbify(img, num_of_labels, kern_size = 3, dilation_rate = 10):
     20     print(type(img))
---> 21     prep_img, contours, hierarchy = prep( img.copy(), kern_size ) # dilate img and check current contour count.
     22     while len(contours) > num_of_labels:
     23         kern_size += dilation_rate # add dilation_rate to kern_size to increase the blob. Remember kern_size must always be odd.

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Comment: what does the command `print(type()img)` and `print(img.shape)` give you?

Answer (score 0):

c_i is a tuple of image,contours and hierarchy.

So at line 45 if you want to pass the image you have to specify c_i[0]